# Is $5^2x^3-x^5 = x^3(x-5)(x+5)$ or $-x^3(5-x)(5+x)$

Tags: factoring

Geogebra's Factor function says that

$5^2x^3-x^5$

is

$-x^3(x-5)(x+5)$

but from what I do, it is positive, $x^3(5+x)(5-x)$

Note the x isnt in the same position

Am I wrong?

Comment: How many more answers saying the same thing do we need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look:
$$5^2x^3-x^5=x^3(5^2-x^2)=x^3(5-x)(5+x)x^3(-1)(x-5)(x+5)=-x^3(x-5)(x+5).$$

Answer (score 2):

$5^2x^3-x^5=x^3(5^2-x^2)=x^3(5-x)(5+x)=-x^3(x-5)(x+5)$

Comment: In the last step, are you multiplying all by -1 ? If so, shouldn't it be $−x^3(+x−5)(-x-5)$ ?

Comment: Oh I see. The -1 mutiplying (x-5) can now multiply $x^3$ because the order of factors is not important. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your answer and Geogebra's answers are equivalent.

$x^3(5+x)(5-x)=-x^3(5+x)(x-5)=-x^3(x+5)(x-5)$.

They just factored out a negative out of $(5-x)$ in order to make it $-(x-5)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not wrong (but the title doesn't reflect the question):
$$
5^2x^3-x^5=x^3(5^2-x^2)=x^3(5-x)(5+x)
$$
You can use $5-x=-(x-5)$ to rewrite it as
$$
-x^3(x-5)(x+5)
$$